# Apache2 / ISPConfig Proxy w. GitLab 502 Error

Tags: apache-http-server, proxy, gitlab

My server is running an ISPConfig control panel on port 8080, so I am trying to configure a proxy for Gitlab on port 9000, however, I am getting a 502 error. There is likely an obvious mistake that I am missing.

```
System information
System:     Debian 10
Current User:   git
Using RVM:  no
Ruby Version:   2.7.2p137
Gem Version:    3.1.4
Bundler Version:2.1.4
Rake Version:   13.0.3
Redis Version:  6.0.12
Git Version:    2.31.1
Sidekiq Version:5.2.9
Go Version: go1.11.6 linux/amd64

GitLab information
Version:    13.12.4
Revision:   02b97bd2a77
Directory:  /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails
DB Adapter: PostgreSQL
DB Version: 12.6
URL:        http://dev.example.com
HTTP Clone URL: http://dev.example.com/some-group/some-project.git
SSH Clone URL:  git@dev.example.com:some-group/some-project.git
Using LDAP: no
Using Omniauth: yes
Omniauth Providers: 

GitLab Shell
Version:    13.18.0
Repository storage paths:
- default:  /var/opt/gitlab/git-data/repositories
GitLab Shell path:      /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-shell
Git:        /opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/git
```

And, my /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/100-dev.example.com.vhost contains:

```
<Directory /var/www/dev.example.com>
        AllowOverride None
                Require all denied
        </Directory>

<VirtualHost *:80>


                                    DocumentRoot /var/www/dev.example.com/web
                        
        ServerName dev.example.com
        ServerAdmin webmaster@dev.example.com


        ErrorLog /var/log/ispconfig/httpd/dev.example.com/error.log

        Alias /error/ "/var/www/dev.example.com/web/error/"
        ErrorDocument 400 /error/400.html
        ErrorDocument 401 /error/401.html
        ErrorDocument 403 /error/403.html
        ErrorDocument 404 /error/404.html
        ErrorDocument 405 /error/405.html
        ErrorDocument 500 /error/500.html
        ErrorDocument 502 /error/502.html
        ErrorDocument 503 /error/503.html


        <Directory /var/www/dev.example.com/web>
                # Clear PHP settings of this website
                <FilesMatch ".+\.ph(p[345]?|t|tml)$">
                        SetHandler None
                </FilesMatch>
                Options +SymlinksIfOwnerMatch
                AllowOverride All
                                Require all granted
                                <Files ~ '.php[s3-6]{0,1}$'>
                                                Require all denied
                                        </Files>
        </Directory>
        <Directory /var/www/clients/client0/web8/web>
                # Clear PHP settings of this website
                <FilesMatch ".+\.ph(p[345]?|t|tml)$">
                        SetHandler None
                </FilesMatch>
                Options +SymlinksIfOwnerMatch
                AllowOverride All
                                Require all granted
                                <Files ~ '.php[s3-6]{0,1}$'>
                                        Require all denied
                                    </Files>
        </Directory>


        # add support for apache mpm_itk
        <IfModule mpm_itk_module>
            AssignUserId web8 client0
        </IfModule>

        <IfModule mod_dav_fs.c>
        # Do not execute PHP files in webdav directory
            <Directory /var/www/clients/client0/web8/webdav>
                <ifModule mod_security2.c>
                    SecRuleRemoveById 960015
                    SecRuleRemoveById 960032
                </ifModule>
                <FilesMatch "\.ph(p3?|tml)$">
                    SetHandler None
                </FilesMatch>
            </Directory>
            DavLockDB /var/www/clients/client0/web8/tmp/DavLock
            # DO NOT REMOVE THE COMMENTS!
            # IF YOU REMOVE THEM, WEBDAV WILL NOT WORK ANYMORE!
      # WEBDAV BEGIN
            # WEBDAV END
        </IfModule>

            
ServerName dev.example.com
  ServerAdmin admin@dev.example.com
    ServerSignature Off

    ProxyPreserveHost On
  
  <Proxy *>
     Require all granted
  </Proxy>
  
  ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:9000/
  ProxyPassReverse / http://dev.example.com/
  
   AllowEncodedSlashes NoDecode
 
 
  <Location />

    Require all granted


  </Location>
  
  
  RewriteEngine on
            
  RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f [OR]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/uploads/.*
  RewriteRule .* http://127.0.0.1:9000%{REQUEST_URI} [P,QSA,NE]

    

</VirtualHost>
```

Can someone shed light on the "obvious mistake" that I am making? THX.

Answer (score 0):

Not guaranteed it will fix the problem, but:

```
ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:9000/
ProxyPassReverse / http://dev.example.com/
```

is wrong, as far as I am aware. It likely should be just:

```
ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:9000/
ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:9000/
```

Comment: tried that... no luck.. thx